# How do I compile C++ from Visual Studio Code on Mac OS? (I can only do it via the terminal)

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, gcc

I can write C/C++ in a text editor (e.g., BBEdit) and then use the Terminal to compile and run the object code.

g++ -o hello hello.c

But now I am experimenting with Visual Studio Code as an IDE. I can't issue the BUILD command and see the output within the IDE. There is something about a tasks.json file.

I tried searching the discussions but only managed to get confused further.

Does anyone even do this? Right now Visual Studio Code has just become a fancy text editor, without integrated compilation.

(ADDENDUM FOR BBEDIT)

I thought I'd edit this post to explain further the workflow for other users using BBEdit or similar text editors.

I have AppleScripts that can be accessed via the BBEdit scripts menu. There are two scripts. One is a BUILD script and one is a RUN script. They take the currently opened filename and send it to the Terminal to execute the compile to g++ and I had to make it two scripts because I couldn't get AppleScript to recognize the Unix command to combine commands using &&

Here is the Build script. You can edit it using Script Editor and place it in the Scripts folder that BBEdit can see:

```
tell application "BBEdit" to set filePath to ((characters 8 thru -1 of (URL of document 1 as string)) as string)

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "g++ " & filePath
end tell
```

and here is the RUN script

```
tell application "BBEdit" to set filePath to ((characters 8 thru -1 of (URL of document 1 as string)) as string)

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "./a.out"
end tell
```

To make these available as shortcuts, just use the Mac OS keyboard shortcuts settings under System Prefs, and make two shortcuts for BBEdit. I used SHIFT + COMMAND + B for Build, and + R for the RUN script.

Comment: please be more specific. Also, if this is what you're asking for, go to Terminal -> new terminal to open the terminal

Comment: The official documentation should help even though you are using gcc instead of clang: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: Ok thanks I will look through the docs again (I tried before)

Comment: I have gone through the docs and now successfully got it to compile and run. Thanks for the link. Somehow I never managed to find the Mac-specific tutorial and kept trying to make sense of the Windows ones, adapting it for Mac (with no luck of course!).

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions:

1. Install XCode Command Line Tools (you might have it already). Its C++ compiler is clang instead of gcc. So instead of calling `gcc hello.c -o hello` you would run `clang hello.c -o hello`. It's a drop-in replacement.
2. [Install homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then install gcc with `brew install gcc`

Comment: Thanks I don't think I have a problem with having the compiler installed. I can use it via the Terminal. I just need to configure VSC to automatically issue the command line commands.

Comment: Oh ok now I understand. I am also a heavy vscode user and I usually prefer to have a terminal (MobaXterm,etc) open in the build directory and type make. The reason is that it the build is really awkward to get configured right and it will change for each project. Also if you are using cmake you will have to issue the configuration commands in the terminal anyway.

Comment: Have you considered Visual Studio (not Code)? VS works in a slightly different way and handles all the build and configuration in a much more integrated way with the IDE

Comment: Ok I am starting to understand why you said the build can change for each project. Then you need to edit the tasks JSON file right? At least that is my current level of understanding. I had installed Studio but then I found out (incorrectly?) that Microsoft is not supporting C++ on Mac and all I found was C#/NET support and other stuff but not C++ so then I uninstalled it and just focused on CODE.